# trim RegExp result

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using RegExp to extract specific words from a string like the following:

```
&lt;div&nbsp;class&nbsp;=&nbsp;&#39;&#39;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;class&nbsp;class&nbsp;
```

My current RegExp statement is this:

```
/(&lt;)[^(&gt;)]*(;|&nbsp;|&#39;|&quote;)(class)?(&nbsp;|&#39;|&quote;|=)/gi
```

In this instance I wan t to match the word 'class' but only if it has specific characters (or ampersands) before and after it. This statement matches:

```
&lt;div&nbsp;class&nbsp;
```

out of the original string, I'm using this in a replace method (to insert text where 'class' was) and I want to keep the other character around it, is there any way of trimming this match down to only select(replace) the word 'class' (in this instance)?

Or is there a better way of doing this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what you want. So you want to match `class` when it's surrounded by some specific characters, and then remove those other characters?

Comment: no i want to remove `class` and keep the other characters BUT ONLY if `class` has specific characters before and after it.

Comment: `[^(&gt;)]*` matches any string that doesn't contain the characters `(`, `&`, `g`, `t`, `;` or `)`.

Comment: I'm not exactly great at regex statements, if you know the correct statement that could go in it's place to match anything that's not `&gt;` please let me know

Comment: One sample way of how you can do it: `"123-zxc-321".replace(/^(\d{3})-zxc-(\d{3})/, "$1-qwe-$2")`. Here `$1` and `$2` represent matches. You can use this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use next code to do this job:

```
var removeSubstring=(function(){
    var fn=function($0,$1,$2,$3){return $1+$3;};
    return function(str,before,after,removed){
        var rg=new RegExp("("+before+")("+removed+")("+after+")","gi");
        return str.replace(rg,fn);
    };
})();

var str="&lt;div&nbsp;class&nbsp;=&nbsp;&#39;&#39;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;class&nbsp;class&nbsp;&lt;div&nbsp;class&nbsp;";
var before="&lt;div&nbsp;";
var after="&nbsp;";
var removed="class";

removeSubstring(str,before,after,removed);
// &lt;div&nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&#39;&#39;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;class&nbsp;class&nbsp;&lt;div&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

But you must ensure what in *`before`*, *`after`* and *`removed`* strings does not contained special *RegExp* format characters (such as `.` `[` `]` `?` `*` and others, see [MDN RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)). Otherwise you must first escape these special characters in *`before`*, *`after`* and *`removed`* strings.

**UPDATE:**

You also can use valid *regular expression* for *`before`*, *`after`* and *`removed`* to make more flexible search. For example next code remove letters *'X'*, *'V'* and *'Z'* but not remove *'x'*, *'v'* and *'z'*:

```
var str="qXd ezrwsvrVa etxceZd";
var before="q|w|e|r";
var after="a|s|d|f";
var removed="z|x|c|v";

removeSubstring(str,before,after,removed);
// "qd ezrwsvra etxced"
```

If you need to replace substring with another string you can use next function:

```
function replaceSubstring(str,before,after,removed,inserted){
    var rg=new RegExp("("+before+")("+removed+")("+after+")","gi");
    return str.replace(rg,function($0,$1,$2,$3){
        // $1 is searched "before" substring
        // $2 is searched "removed" substring
        // $3 is searched "after" substring
        return $1+(inserted||"")+$3;
    });
};


var str="qXd ezrwsvrVa etxceZd";
var before="q|w|e|r";
var after="a|s|d|f";
var removed="z|x|c|v";
replaceSubstring(str,before,after,removed,"DDDD")
// "qDDDDd ezrwsvrDDDDa etxceDDDDd"
```

Comment: +1 for the concept, however the content is dynamic (what I've given is just an example) meaning the `before` has to be `&lt;` and a statement that means `anything any number of times *except* &gt;` then `class` (in this case) and `after` has to be either `&nbsp;`,  `=`, `&quote;` or `&#39;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var match = /your regex here/.exec(myString)
match = match.replace('class','')
```